# How to replace a rootfs with another one?

Tags: raspbian, sd-card, filesystem, root, fstab

I have 2 sd cards, one with raspbian and one with debian builds.
I need to replace the rootfs in my raspbian sd card with the one in my debian sd card.

How can I do this? And, what are the changes (if any) required to be made?
I'm a newbie, please help.

Comment: In effect you are cloning the cards as the root file system is everything but the /boot partition.  Is that your intention?

Comment: @joan.. Yes, but I need to retain the kernel.

Comment: Are the kernels the same version number?  uname -a should give the version.  The kernel is Linux and as far as I know should be distribution agnostic (neither hard nor soft float).

Comment: @joan. I had actually recompiled the kernel to add support for an additional i2c.

Comment: I believe I need to create a tarball out of debian rootfs, delete the raspian rootfs partition, create a new one and extract this tarball there. Will this work?

Comment: I don't know.  It's not something I've done.  Why not just copy the original SD card to the copy?  Should work if they are the same size.  Perhaps search for cloning SD cards.  The size of the non-copied /boot is tiny compared to the rest.

Answer (score 1):

### Terminology

We will refer to the debian sd card as the *source* and the rasbian sd card as the *destination*.

The following operations should be done on a linux machine other than your raspberry pi.

### Instructions

#### Backup Destination SD Card

1. Place your destination sd card into your sd card reader.
2. `sudo dd if=/dev/sdXN of=./destination-backup.iso`

X should be a letter, and N should be the partition number.  This will create `destination-backup.iso` in your current directory.

#### Create Source ISO

1. Place your source sd card into your sd card reader.
2. `sudo dd if=/dev/sdXN of=./source-backup.iso`
3. Place your destination sd card into your sd card reader.
4. `sudo dd if=./source-backup.iso of=/dev/sdXN`

X should be a letter, and N should be the partition number.  This will create `source-backup.iso` in your current directory.  After that is created, you will be placing that data onto the root partition of the destination sd card.

#### 'Resize' partition

1. `sudo resize2fs /dev/sdXN`

You should run this if your filesystem sizes are different (which they typically will be).  This will automatically expand/contract your filesystem size.

### Disclaimer

This assumes that what you're doing will work.  For example, if you replace any root filesystem with another root filesystem, you could potentially run into issues with the operating system.

There is a potential for dataloss using these commands.  Please be sure to make the backups (as recommended).